# Coding standards and best programming practices for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-applications, yui

I am looking for some decent coding standards and best programming practices for JavaScript?

I have a C# background.  How are controls named on the web page?  If you have a button, how would you name the id property?  In ASP.NET we would call it something like btnSearch.  Treeviews would be something like tvUsers.

I am using the YUI API, but the same would apply here.

Comment: @NeXXeuS - The link is http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Douglas Crockford complete book, watch the videos first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no definite style guide like [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for JS. [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/) contains some good information on its quirks, though. You'll likely learn a trick or two by studying it. :)

Considering your id question I rather tend to avoid ids when writing applications. This is simply due to the fact that it's way too easy to end up with clashes.

Instead I like construct my elements dynamically via JS (direct ref to elem) and to use class attributes for styling (ie. ".clear.button"). I'm not sure if anyone else does it this way, though...

Since you are dealing with YUI it's likely you have some specific conventions there.

Comment: How do you create you elements in JS?  What would you do when submitting a form and you maybe need a reference to a textbox?  Would an id help in getting a reference to a specific element?

Comment: DOM provides means for creating elements (createElement, appendChild) that many frameworks wrap. My case is a bit special since I don't have to deal with forms and such in my apps. I think there are some standard ways to handle that, though. Perhaps you just generate the JS on the server side and get the ids that way. I recall doing something like that with Django.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a C# background. How are
>   controls named on the web page?

The client id is a property of the control:
controlId.ClientID

Example:

```
string MyJavaScriptControlId = btnSearch.ClientID;
```

Or, in your aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    htmlElement = document.getElementById('<% tvUsers.ClientID %>');
</script>
```

Comment: I was just wondering how to name your elements in JS.  The C# part was just how I named them in C#.  Would you name it is the same, or there another naming convention to follow when using JS.

Comment: @Brendan, by default the ID of C# control is not passed to the client. The client ID is generated at runtime, and stored in the element as ClientID. You can change how clientIDs are generated with ClientIDMode option. If set ClientIDMode="static", then the clientID will be the same as background ID.